# response code 500 Android POST method

Tags: java, android, response

I have read many posts with the same problem and tried to apply their solutions, but no one worked for me. I am pretty new to Java and Android. The url is "https", this is not an error. My java code is the following:

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);        

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_pago);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
            public void onClick(View v)  {
                try {
                    new SendPostRequest().execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }




    public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){}

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://www.myweb.com/login_app.php"); 

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("precio", "5000");
                postDataParams.put("texto", "f...h");
                Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            String key= itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Checking the log file, I found many messages like the following:

```
81.184.8.77 - - [23/Aug/2016:12:54:05 +0200] "POST /login_app.php HTTP/1.1" 500 379 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; Android SDK built for x86 Build/KK)" "-"
81.184.8.77 - - [23/Aug/2016:12:59:37 +0200] "POST /login_app.php HTTP/1.1" 500 10793 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; ONE E1001 Build/LMY47V)" "-"
81.184.8.77 - - [23/Aug/2016:13:01:05 +0200] "POST /login_app.php HTTP/1.1" 500 10807 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; Android SDK built for x86 Build/KK)" "-"
81.184.8.77 - - [23/Aug/2016:13:01:07 +0200] "POST /login_app.php HTTP/1.1" 500 379 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; Android SDK built for x86 Build/KK)" "-"
```

Comment: 500 is an internal Server error. So look in the Server logfile to find out what is happend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the original post

Comment: This is the Access log, there you can not see any error.

Comment: Ok, do you know the location of the access log? I have read that it is in a folder called logs.zip; isn't it?

Comment: on which os you php script runs?

Comment: Look in your php.ini, there you should find the Location of the error log

Comment: Thank you for your time. I do not have a php.ini file in my server. I have got a page in my domain provider account to ser variables like "post_max_size" or "display_errors". I will contact them and update the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the solution: I needed to set `allow_url_fopen` value on. This variable can be found in the `php.ini`, as the other people well said and in my case, that file could not be found into the server, I had to go to my domain provider webpage, enter to the private area and look for php configuration.

I hope it helps some others, and the you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered this issue a while ago. The logs in the server will help you solve the issue.

Just for the record, logs for such errors are usually found in the following location: `var/log/apache2/error.log` You may need to make some change to the php.ini file to log these errors.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can not find the location of the log.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about different types of HTTP status codes here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

**500 Internal Server Error**

A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer